# How to configure caching in webpack 5

Tags: webpack-5

I want to know whether the cache configuration of webpack5 in production and development will be automatically enabled and what their configuration is. When will the cache become invalid? Will the cache become invalid if I modify the business code?

I found that webpack5 does not enable cache by default, but I don’t know whether cache is needed in development and production environments, and whether cache is needed in production.